# Which is better for performance DateA <= ISNULL(DateB, '29991231) or (DateA < DateB OR DateA IS NULL)

Tags: sql-server

This is a common pattern I use in SELECT statements in JOINs, and in CONSTRAINTs, but now I am thinking it isn't sargable, so might be a bad pattern to use?

Where a statement is:

```
(DateA < DateB OR DateB IS NULL)
```

I tend to replace this with the simpler:

```
DateA < ISNULL(DateB, '29991231')
```

i.e. just put in a very high date where the date I am comparing to is NULL.  Let's assume that there are no dates in my database more than a year or two into the future.

I prefer the "ISNULL" version as it doesn't require extra brackets, reads better in my opinion, and is easier to maintain.

What are the downsides?

(Note I can see there are some similar questions around this, but not with date ranges.)

This is what I used to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (DateA DATE, DateB DATE);
INSERT INTO #table SELECT '20170101', '20180205';
INSERT INTO #table SELECT '20170101', '20180209';
INSERT INTO #table SELECT '20170101', '20180310';
INSERT INTO #table SELECT '20170101', NULL;
CREATE INDEX ix$table$A ON #table (DateA);
CREATE INDEX ix$table$B ON #table (DateB);
SELECT * FROM #table WHERE DateA < GETDATE() AND (DateB > GETDATE() OR DateB IS NULL);
SELECT * FROM #table WHERE DateA < GETDATE() AND ISNULL(DateB, '29991231') > GETDATE();
```

And when I run the last two statements the execution plan shows a 50%:50% split.

Comment: Your second option is nonSARGable because you wrapped the column in a function. But if that is a variable and not a function it should be fine. But why not test this and look at the execution plans?

Comment: I did some tests, with indexes, without indexes, and got a 50:50 execution plan every time.  Which confused me, as I didn't expect this to be the case.  I might try with a "real" table with millions of rows...

Comment: With so few values, you can't draw any major conclusions here.  I expect you would certainly see a difference on a table with thousands of records and many different `DateB` values.

Comment: Just tried it on a table with half a million rows, and the execution plans were identical.  I think the issue here is that the "end date", i.e. DateB in my example query, would never form part of an index anyway, so it doesn't really matter if the expression is sargable or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the second version:

```
DateA < ISNULL(DateB, '29991231')
```

Is that the `DateB` column appears inside the `ISNULL` function, and therefore may not be sargable.  That is to say, the optimizer may not be able to use an index on the `DateB` column in the second version.  On the other hand, the first version would not appear to have this limitation.

If `DateB` is actually just a constant, that either version should have a similar execution plan.  I answered under the assumption that `DateB` is an actual column with different values across your table.

Comment: Agreed, and this is what I expected to find.  In the real world this is usually going to be a column that doesn't form part of an index (usually start/ end dates), but even when I tested this with/ without indexes I found no difference in execution plans.

Comment: @RichardHansell There is another issue, the cardinality of the `DateB` column.  If there are only a few different values in `DateB`, then _any_ index might not help that much.  So, the query plans might be very similar, but that could be due to an index not helping in the first place.

Comment: I switched to a bigger "real world" table. There are 1,751,817 rows of data, of which 417,820 are NULL, and 3,534 distinct DateBs.  I still saw no difference between the two queries, even after forcing an index on the DateB column.  I think the cardinality is the issue.  Interestingly there is a missing index suggestion in the execution plan, but it's an enormous covering index (which I would never want to create IRL).

Comment: @RichardHansell You sound like you know more SQL Server than I know :-) ... I would say come up with an example where the index is working, and then benchmark your two versions.